# Rerender vue-chart in a nuxt.js project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, nuxt.js, vue-chartjs

I am working on a nuxt project and need to draw some charts. For that I use vue-chartjs as a plugin. Unfortunately the chart-data is fetched  after the chart is drawn which results in an empty chart. I can't find a way to access the plugin and rerender the chart when the data is ready. Here is the code for the plugin:

```js
// plugins/vue-chart.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import { Bar, Doughnut, Line, Pie } from 'vue-chartjs'

const registerComponent = function (name, originalComponent) {
  Vue.component(
    name,
    {
      extends: originalComponent,
      props: ['data', 'options'],
      mounted () {
        this.renderChart(this.data, this.options)
      },
      updated () {
        this.renderChart(this.data, this.options)
      }
    }
  )
}

registerComponent('BarChart', Bar)
registerComponent('DoughnutChart', Doughnut)
registerComponent('LineChart', Line)
registerComponent('PieChart', Pie)
```

And here is how I use the plugin to draw a line chart:

`components/Charts.vue`

```html
<template>
  <client-only>
    <LineChart :data="lineData" :options="options" />
  </client-only>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      loading: true,
      lineData: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Close',
            data: [],
          },
          {
            label: 'High',
            data: [],
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
          x: {
            display: true,
            title: {
              display: true,
            },
          },
          y: {
            display: true,
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: 'Value',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    try {
      const response = await this.$axios.get('/api/entries')
      if (response.status === 200) {
        for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
          this.lineData.labels.push(response.data[i].date)
          this.lineData.datasets[0].data.push(response.data[i].close)
          this.lineData.datasets[1].data.push(response.data[i].high)
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

I am happy about any suggestions on how to solve this!

**Edit**
I had to downgrade the versions of `chart.js` and `vue-chartjs` so that the project compiles.

Here is my `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "xyz",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev-fe": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext \".js,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint": "npm run lint:js"
  },
  "dependencies":
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.1",
    "core-js": "^3.15.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.7",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.14.7",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^6.0.1",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.0.2",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint": "^7.29.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.12.1",
    "postcss": "^8.3.5"
  }
}
```

I use pretty much use the default in `nuxt.config.js` except that I added

```js
{ src: '~/plugins/vue-chart.js', mode: 'client' }
```

to the plugins.

Comment: So, the chart is not reactive with the fetched data? You could maybe try to give an `updated()` lifecycle hook to `vue-chart.js`, with the same content as the `mounted()` one. Otherwise, the usage of `asyncData()` to fetch the data is still a possibility (it will block the render of the page until the request is done).

Comment: Do you mind sharing a [repro] or more of your configuration btw? Looks like the packages I've tried to install are compatible with Vue3 only.

Comment: Also, check [this caveat](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects) since you _may_ be concerned. Not sure.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply! I added my `package.json` for you to reproduce the project. I did as you suggested and added an `updated()` hook to `vue-chart.js`. Also I tried fetching the data using `fetch()`(as the component is not a page component I can't use `asyncData()`). Still not working unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, I got a working example with the following.

Here is my `vue-chartjs.js` plugin

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Bar, Doughnut, Line, Pie, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'

const registerComponent = function (name, originalComponent) {
  Vue.component(name, {
    extends: originalComponent,
    mixins: [mixins.reactiveProp],
    props: {
      chartData: {
        type: Object,
        default: () => {},
      },
      chartOptions: {
        type: Object,
        default: () => {},
      },
    },
    mounted() {
      this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.chartOptions)
    },
  })
}

registerComponent('BarChart', Bar)
registerComponent('DoughnutChart', Doughnut)
registerComponent('LineChart', Line)
registerComponent('PieChart', Pie)
```

`/pages/index.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <line-chart
      :key="updated"
      :chart-data="lineData"
      :chart-options="options"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import FakeData from '@/fake.json'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      updated: 0,
      lineData: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Data One',
            backgroundColor: '',
            data: [],
          },
          {
            label: 'Data Two',
            backgroundColor: '',
            data: [],
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
          x: {
            display: true,
            title: {
              display: true,
            },
          },
          y: {
            display: true,
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: 'Value',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    }
  },
  async fetch() {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log('fake API title fetched:', data.title)

    const actualData = FakeData.data
    for (let i = 0; i < actualData.length; i++) {
      this.lineData.labels.push(actualData[i].date)
      this.lineData.datasets[0].backgroundColor = actualData[i].color1
      this.lineData.datasets[0].data.push(actualData[i].close)
      this.lineData.datasets[1].backgroundColor = actualData[i].color2
      this.lineData.datasets[1].data.push(actualData[i].high)
    }
    this.updated++
  },
}
</script>
```

and my fake `.json` API data, because I didn't have an API to get some real data

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "date": "Jan",
      "color1": "#EC368D",
      "color2": "#51E5FF",
      "close": "0.4",
      "high": "0.7"
    },
    {
      "date": "Feb",
      "color1": "#EC368D",
      "color2": "#51E5FF",
      "close": "0.2",
      "high": "0.5"
    },
    {
      "date": "Mar",
      "color1": "#EC368D",
      "color2": "#51E5FF",
      "close": "0.6",
      "high": "0.8"
    }
  ]
}
```

I still mocked an API call, so it should work great as an example for you.

The idea behind this was to use the [`key` hack](https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/677#issuecomment-808920024), which is not really that good but eh, the maintainer is not really into helping people properly IMO.

So this is still the best that is available.

Here is my final result and the related [Github repo](https://github.com/kissu/so-chartjs).

[image]