# Weird issue when I use google chart or chartjs with Vuejs 2 and Laravel

Tags: vue.js

Hi I am using vuejs with chartjs but I am getting a weird issue I though that it could be the library but I do not know what it can be, I am using Vuejs 2 I do exactly what this tutorial says:

[Look Tutorial](https://www.tutofox.com/vue/tutorial-laravel-vue-charts/)

And I get an error then I tried to use google chart with Vuejs and I am getting same error, the error is this one:

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at generateChart (243.js:13430:71)
at Module../node_modules/vue-chartjs/dist/index.js (243.js:13577:29)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:64:30)
at Module../resources/js/components/LineChart.js (244.js:142:69)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:64:30)
at Module../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./resources/js/views/Grafico.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (244.js:12:82)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:64:30)
at Module../resources/js/views/Grafico.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (244.js:206:198)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:64:30)
at Module../resources/js/views/Grafico.vue (244.js:168:95)
```

I installed the package with the npm I do step by step and I get same error in both cases what could it be? what is that error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

downgrading the version can help solve this issue. I was getting the similar error.
version to install

```
npm install chart.js@2.7.1 vue-chartjs@3.4.0 --save
```

Or can follow this example : [example for vue-chartjs and nuxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71846172/rerender-vue-chart-in-a-nuxt-js-project)